# VirtualBox still appears installed and active after running "sudo apt-get remove virtualbox"

Tags: virtualbox, software-uninstall

I am quite new to ubuntu.

I uninstalled VB in my Ubuntu 16.10 machine.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove virtualbox
```

Shouldn't this completely uninstall VB from my system? Despite running those commands, I still have VB installed and active.

What should I do?
Any help for this newbie? Thank you

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Did you restart the system after that removal?

Comment: installed VB by downloading from website and software installation but not via terminal.

Comment: VB remains installed and working even after restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you mentioned that you *"installed VB by downloading from website"* therefore you installed it using a `.deb` package and Ubuntu Software (the default "app store").
Now, to uninstall, just search it at Ubuntu Software and proceed accordingly or, in Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --remove packagename
```

where "packagename" is the exact name of the file you downloaded from their website.